# spring data web 'like' expression parameter is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, hateoas

The repository name is MemberMasterRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "memberMaster", path = "memberMaster")
    public interface MemberMasterRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MemberMaster,Integer> {

        List<MemberMaster> findByLastNameLike(@Param ("lastname") String substring);

    }
```

under previous versions of this interface extending `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` this worked I believe when appending '%' to the character string on the parameter. In a junit test with MemberMasterRepository autowired, this works.

Trying to access it via an http client with a GET to:
http://localhost:8090/memberMaster/search/findByLastNameLike?lastname=simpkin%

I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterMetadataProvider$ParameterMetadata.prepare(ParameterMetadataProvider.java:226)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.bind(CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:111)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:172)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:163)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.invokeBinding(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:207)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:134)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:166)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:110)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:99)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.findByLastNameLike(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:203)
at org.springframework.data.rest.core.invoke.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invoke(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:283)
at org.springframework.data.rest.core.invoke.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeQueryMethod(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:230)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeQueryMethod(RepositorySearchController.java:285)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:175)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Setting the breakpoint at `SevletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).doInvoke` line:221 that from the args that the `ServletWebRequest`, the parameters map has a size of 0. 
From what I can tell appending '%' to the parameter value is resulting in it not being included in the request.

Hoping not a duplicate. Thanks in advance. Wonder if Oliver Gierke will chime in on this one.

Comment: shouldn't the function name be `findByLastnameLike` instead of `findByLastNameLike`.

Comment: No. MemberMaster has a property lastName not lastname.

Comment: Also, I think I should be returning Page not List

Comment: then shouldn't that map with `@Param ("lastname")`?

Comment: I completely agree. If I drop the %   lastname=simpkin I get 200 with an empty object { } (the like expression not performing correctly) because the 'like' expression I believe wanted % appended but by doing so that key value pair isn't included in the parameter map. If the like expression worked, I'd get a collection of MemberMaster's

Comment: my doubt is regarding casing.. as per your method name, your variable name should be `lastName`, however in `@Param` you are using `lastname`.. i was wondering, will that be the issue? also can you please post `MemberMaster`.

Answer (score 0):

% is a special character used for substitution. After the % put '25' which is the ASCII code for '%'. So the correct URL is: http://localhost:8090/memberMaster/search/findByLastNameLike?lastname=simpkin%25